# React native set array of dictionary in Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I need to show data in SectionList Component. for that i need to require data set to in array with dictionary.

Please check below code. where dictionary contains two value

**Data : array** and **title : String**

```js
var dict = {};
dict['data'] = [
   {"timing":[1,1,1,1],"title":"sunny"},
   {"timing":[1,1,1,1],"title":"sunny"},
];
dict['title'] = "1";
const arrV = [dict]

console.log('item',arrV)
document.getElementById('result').innerText = JSON.stringify(arrV, null, 2)
```

```html
<pre id="result"></div>
```

But When i print arrV.... there is no array in data key.**(Array(0))** see the attached image. I need array with two objects. How can i achive that

[image]

Comment: If you run that very same snippet in the browser console, data is an array with 2 elements. I think there is something else going on there, probably the code actually executing it not the one you posted here

Answer (score 1):

**Dictionary** is normally called **object** in Javascript, If you want an array with two objects, here's how you can do that:

```
var dict1 = {};
var dict2 = {};
dict1["data"] = [
   {"timing":[1,1,1,1],"title":"sunny"},
   {"timing":[1,1,1,1],"title":"sunny"},
  ];
dict2["title"] = "1";
const arrV = [dict1,dict2]
console.log('item: ',arrV)
```

Here's how the result will look like

```
item:  [
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "timing": [
          1,
          1,
          1,
          1
        ],
        "title": "sunny"
      },
      {
        "timing": [
          1,
          1,
          1,
          1
        ],
        "title": "sunny"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "1"
  }
]
```

Comment: Nope, the array would have 2 entries: an object with data key and another object with title key. Your example result only has 1 object with both data and title keys and it's not the actual output of your code